# ZURB Foundation 5 3rd party javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a problem with Zurb Foundation and 3rd party javascripts.

I'm creating website in Foundation 5 (because of nice responsive design) and everything works great until I try to add my own javascripts on the page inside the script tags.

When I remove the `$(document).foundation();` call at the end of the document, everything I've wrote in JavaScript begin to work.

What is wrong? How should I include 3rd party JavaScript code and call it, to make it work without conflict?

I'm using Notepad++ to code.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, to be honest. A sample of your code might be helpful for us to point out the problem.

Comment: @KemalFadillah: No need to remove that last line from the question.

Comment: I just thought it is irrelevant from the issue at hand.

Comment: Solved. The problem was, that 3rd party script needed different version of jQuery to work. Adding multiple instances of jQuery (with noConflict()) allowed me to solve the problem.

Comment: @endrju100 If you've found the solution, feel free to put it as an answer. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Foundation 5 uses jQuery 2, which may not be compatable with the 3rd Party scripts you are including.  Try add an older version of jQuery (along with the version that's included with Foundation).  It's possible to do so without there being a conflict, [see this post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page).